# WebApp delete cookie

Tags: ios, caching, cookies, web-applications

When I delete my webapp and relink it to my home screen all cookies remained on my iPhone. Even if I delete the browser cache and all website data in the safari settings. How can I delete the entire webapp with all data related to it?

Edit: I've got a cookie based notification badge within my App. I want to reset/delete the cookie